# How change delay time loading cordova app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

This code not work in my index.html

```
    app.run(function($cordovaSplashscreen) {
         setTimeout(function() {
          $cordovaSplashscreen.hide()
         }, 100)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line in the config.xml file :

```
<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="100" />
```

where 100 is a time in milliseconds.
It is the time until your application is crashing.

[EDIT]

The error you get is because the LoadTimeoutValue is not long enough. Obviously your app need some time to be load. Try with a higher value : 10000 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Add this below line to your `config.xml` file in your project's `root` directory.

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

where 3000 is a time in milliseconds which means of 3 seconds. Set your own time here.

Comment: I added this <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" / and nothing